# Use GPU only for calculations on desktop

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have a desktop with an NVIDIA GPU, and in the last few weeks it became pretty unstable. I suspect the issue is due to an update of the NVIDIA drivers for CUDA or the cuda toolkit.

Problems include windows freezing and/or becoming unresponsive, super key not working and more. I'm running CUDA 10.2 and nvidia-driver-440. The Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS.

As a temporary solution, I would like to use the GPU only for running TensorFlow/PyTorch, and use the Intel chip for managing the graphical interface. How can I do that? I tried the following steps but they didn't fix things:

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
sudo reboot
```

Of course, let me know if you have tips on how to fix the issue at the root and make the system usable!

Comment: 1. yes, I run TensorFlow on my desktop recently. 2. My point is that if I activate the NVIDIA GPU and the cuda drivers, the graphical interface becomes unusable. I updated the question as you suggested.